# How can I set the value of a field in a form that I am fetching from another component with Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

I'm taking my first steps in Angular and it's having a bit of a hard time getting started with the basics. Basically I have a list of people and I want to navigate to the details of one of the people to modify them but I am unable to get their ID to appear on the form. I have managed to get the id to the url. It's something...

component1 html

```
    <form [formGroup]="formOwner" (submit)="submit()">
  <div class="example-container">
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>ID</mat-label>
      <input matInput formControlName="id">
    </mat-form-field>
    <br>
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>First Name</mat-label>
      <input matInput formControlName="name">
    </mat-form-field>
    <br>
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Salary</mat-label>
      <input matInput formControlName="salary">
    </mat-form-field>
    <br>
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Age</mat-label>
      <input matInput formControlName="age">
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit">Actualizar</button>
  </form>
```

component1.ts

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Employer } from 'src/app/core/interfaces/employers-response.interface';
import { EmployersService } from 'src/app/services/employers.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modificar-empleados',
  templateUrl: './modificar-empleados.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modificar-empleados.component.sass']
})
export class ModificarEmpleadosComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() formValue: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  formOwner: FormGroup
  static formOwner: any;
  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get['id']);
    this.initForm();
  }

  initForm(){
    this.formOwner = this.formBuilder.group({
      id: [],
      name: [],
      salary: [],
      age: []
    });
  }

  submit(){
    this.formValue.emit(this.formOwner.value);
    //console.log('from form',this.formOwner.value);
  }

}
```

component2.html

```
<app-modificar-empleados (formValue)="getFormValue($event)"></app-modificar-empleados>
```

component2.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EmployersService } from 'src/app/services/employers.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-editempleado',
  templateUrl: './editempleado.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./editempleado.component.sass']
})
export class EditempleadoComponent implements OnInit {

  id: String = '';

  constructor(private employers: EmployersService, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
  }

  updateEmployer(values){
    this.employers.updateEmployee(values).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log('respuesta al actualizar empleado',res);
    });
  }

  getFormValue(values){
    this.updateEmployer(values);
  }

}
```

In the people table I have a button that invokes this method to navigate to the URL of each one. It has a parameter of the ID of each person

```
edit(id: number){
  this.router.navigate(['/editar', id]);
}
```

I am thankful for any kind of help. Thanks so much!

Comment: One option would be that based on received id (that you provide during router navigation) make an API call and retrieve employee data in your `ModificarEmpleadosComponent `

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to emit the id, change your function to

```
  submit(){
    this.formValue.emit(this.formOwner.get('id').value);
    //console.log('from form',this.formOwner.value);
  }
```

As a side note, you are probably not initializing your form properly. It would be better to initialize it by giving it the original/default values, like

```
  initForm(){
    this.formOwner = this.formBuilder.group({
      id: 0,
      name: '',
      salary: 0,
      age: 0
    });
  }
```

or if you need to add validators, then

```
  initForm(){
    this.formOwner = this.formBuilder.group({
      id: [0, Validator.Required],
      ...
    });
  }
```